# How to stop all goroutines that wait for sync.Cond?

Tags: go, concurrency

I wrote a Queue class

```
type Queue struct {
    data     []interface{}
    cond     *sync.Cond
}

func New() Queue {
    return Queue{
        data:     []interface{}{},
        cond:     sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{}),
        chanStop: make(chan interface{}),
    }
}

func (q *Queue) Push(val interface{}) {
    q.cond.L.Lock()

    q.data = append(q.data, val)

    q.cond.Signal()
    q.cond.L.Unlock()
}

func (q *Queue) Pop() (interface{}, bool) {

    q.cond.L.Lock()
    for len(q.data) == 0 {
        q.cond.Wait()
    }

    retVal := q.data[0]

    q.data = q.data[1:]

    q.cond.L.Unlock()

    return retVal, true
}

func (q *Queue) Close() {

}
```

If the queue is empty `Pop()` callers will be blocked. Is there any way to stop waiting all routines that are blocked with `Pop()` by any Cond calls?

Of course I can do something like

```
type Queue struct {
    data     []interface{}
    cond     *sync.Cond
    chanStop chan interface{}
}


func (q *Queue) Pop() (interface{}, bool) {

    var retVal interface{}
    retFlag := false

    select {
    case <-q.chanStop:

    case <-func() <-chan interface{} {
        out := make(chan interface{})

        go func() {
            defer close(out)

            q.cond.L.Lock()
            for len(q.data) == 0 {
                q.cond.Wait()
            }

            retVal = q.data[0]
            retFlag = true

            q.data = q.data[1:]

            q.cond.L.Unlock()
        }()
        return out
    }():
    }

    return retVal, retFlag
}

func (q *Queue) Close() {
    close(q.chanStop)
}
```

But maybe there's some way to stop waiting without all this `select` verbosity?

UPDATE:

Actually it might be done so:

```
package queue

import "sync"

type Queue struct {
    data     []interface{}
    cond     *sync.Cond
    stop     bool
}

func New() Queue {
    return Queue{
        data:     []interface{}{},
        cond:     sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{}),
        stop: false,
    }
}

func (q *Queue) Push(val interface{}) {
    q.cond.L.Lock()

    q.data = append(q.data, val)

    q.cond.Signal()
    q.cond.L.Unlock()
}

func (q *Queue) Pop() (interface{}, bool) {
    q.cond.L.Lock()
    for len(q.data) == 0 && !q.stop {
        q.cond.Wait()
    }

    if q.stop {
        q.cond.L.Unlock()
        return nil, false
    }

    retVal := q.data[0]

    q.data = q.data[1:]

    q.cond.L.Unlock()

    return retVal, true
}

func (q *Queue) Close() {
    q.cond.L.Lock()

    q.stop = true

    q.cond.Broadcast()
    q.cond.L.Unlock()
}
```

And yes, `sync.Cond` is sooo weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wake all clients waiting in `Pop()` with [`Cond.Broadcast()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond.Broadcast), but then you would also have to handle if `q.data` is empty and there's nothing to return.

Moreover, if clients keep calling `Pop()` after the queue has been closed, you would also need to check if the queue had been closed before and not enter the waiting state but return early.

Generally [`sync.Cond`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond) is under-documented, it is incompatible with other Go synchronization patterns (e.g. `select`), and many don't consider it to be a useful synchronization primitive in Go, and potentially it will be removed in Go 2, see [details](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21165).

Channels may be used instead of `sync.Cond`, e.g. closing the channel corresponds to `Cond.Broadcast()`, sending a value on the channel corresponds to `Cond.Signal()`.

Back to your example. The simplest concurrency-safe queue is a buffered channel itself. Push operation is a [send](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements) on the channel, pop operation is a [receive](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) from the channel. Channels are safe for concurrent use.

One thing that a buffered channel "doesn't know" is that it has a fixed buffer size, and once created, the buffer size cannot be changed. Still, I think it's a small price to pay to allocate a big buffer prior and not worry about anything later. Sends on a channel whose buffer is full would not panic "just" block until someone receives from the channel.